# How to filter the left join in sql

Tags: sql, vb.net, filter

This is the code:

```
SELECT c.ChapterNo, c.Title, l.LessonNo, l.Title 
FROM Chapter c 
LEFT JOIN Lesson l ON c.ChapterNo = l.ChapterNo
```

but i want to filter the Chapter Table by Chapter's Description A. I already used this:

```
SELECT c.ChapterNo, c.Title, l.LessonNo, l.Title 
FROM Chapter c 
LEFT JOIN Lesson l ON c.ChapterNo = l.ChapterNo 
WHERE c.Desc = 'geometry'
```

and this

```
SELECT c.ChapterNo, c.Title, l.LessonNo, l.Title 
FROM Chapter c 
LEFT JOIN Lesson l ON c.ChapterNo = l.ChapterNo AND c.Desc = 'geometry'
```

but it does not work. I dont know why...

Comment: Second query looks good.  What do you mean by *does not work* ? Add sample data ,your current result and expected result

Comment: nothing shows when i run. i want to filter the first table by the geometry as description. i want to return just the chapter numbers with geometry as description

Answer (score 1):

It does not work because you need to put the condition in the `where` clause:

```
SELECT c.ChapterNo, c.Title, l.LessonNo, l.Title
FROM Chapter c LEFT JOIN
     Lesson l
     ON c.ChapterNo = l.ChapterNo 
WHERE c.Desc = 'geometry';
```

The rules for a `left join` are simple:  Keep all the rows in the first table regardless of whether or not the `WHERE` clause evaluates to true.  So, a filter on the first table does not reduce the number of rows.

Comment: what does it mean? i should not use the left join?

Comment: @ABCDE . . . You should use the `left join` if you want values in `c` that have no matching rows in `l`.

Comment: @ABCDE . . . Have you run this query?  It does the filtering you want.

Comment: is 'geometry' the actual value or is it part of a longer value like 'Principles of Geomtery'? If it is, you must use the LIKE operator